# How to set proxy server in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to send email from SQL Server using these piece of code:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Notif Sender',
          @recipients = 'example@example.com',
          @copy_recipients ='example2@example.com',
          @blind_copy_recipients='example3@example.com',
          @subject = 'TEST Message',
          @body =   '<h4>TEST BODY</h4>', 
          @body_format = 'HTML';
```

I have configured database mail and have both public and default profile 'Notif Sender'.

But mailer fails to connect to the smtp server.

What might be the issue?

I thought I need to set local network's proxy server, so I set it in Internet Options of IE, but it didn't help. Proxy server is properly set there as I am able to surf the Internet without problems.

Here is a line from log file:

```
11/10/2014 15:52:04,,Error,52,
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. 
(Sending Mail using Account 2 (2014-11-10T15:52:04). 
Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. 
(A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time<c/> 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 64.233.162.109:587).<nl/>),
3672,23,,10.11.2014 15:52:04,sa
```

Comment: This is not a proxy error... possible a firewall issue.

Comment: I doubt you need to set up your proxy server for smtp traffic. Proxy servers normally only filter http/https traffic.  I think the problem is that your sql server can't connect to your smtp server.

Comment: http://www.mssqlcity.com/articles/adm/mail_troubleshooting.htm